# "CONNECTIVITY_ISSUE" error while using android-uber-sdk

Tags: android, authentication, uber-api

I am receiving an authentication error "`CONNECTIVITY_ISSUE`" when I try to login using android sdk LoginManager in **sandbox mode.**

```
SessionConfiguration config = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
            .setClientId(Constants.UBER_CLIENTID) 
            .setEnvironment(SessionConfiguration.Environment.SANDBOX) 
            .setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.PROFILE, Scope.RIDE_WIDGETS,Scope.REQUEST)) 
            .build();
UberSdk.initialize(config);
    accessTokenManager = new AccessTokenManager(this);
    LoginCallback loginCallback = new LoginCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLoginCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoginError(@NonNull AuthenticationError error) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoginSuccess(@NonNull AccessToken accessToken) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthorizationCodeReceived(@NonNull String authorizationCode) {
        authorizationCode=authorizationCode;
        }
    };
    loginManager = new LoginManager(accessTokenManager, loginCallback);
    if (accessTokenManager.getAccessToken() == null) {
        loginManager.setRedirectForAuthorizationCode(true);
        loginManager.login(this);
    }
```

I have followed uber developer documentation and I am not able to solve this error. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: looks like you are missing the redirect uri from your `SessionConfiguration`, have you tried adding it in like this: `.setRedirectUri("YOUR_REDIRECT_URI")` ? more information in the [readme](https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk#sdk-configuration)

Comment: Thank you. That fixed the problem :)

Comment: Do you mind selecting my answer below as the correct one, so that other people with the same question can find it? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the redirect uri from your `SessionConfiguration`,  try adding it in like this:

```
.setRedirectUri("YOUR_REDIRECT_URI").
```

More information in the [readme](https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk#sdk-configuration)